# How do I divide 8 byte integer to four 2 bytes Hexadecimal in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I've got school task but IDK How to design the code at all...

The function that it need to do is,

1. input 8 byte integer (I think it has to be unsigned long long type, cause input number has to be 0 or more)
2. divide input number to four 2 bytes and save it each variable.
   <<for example, input number is 18446744073709551615
   then, it will be 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 in binary.
   (it doesn't have to convert to binary, just show you how to divide)
   divide like this 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111 in four part>>
3. and make each part to hexadecimal
   <like this, 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111 / 1111111111111111
   -> ffff / ffff / ffff / ffff>
4. finally, make ffff / ffff / ffff / ffff to decimal number 65535 / 65535 / 65535 / 65535

Sorry, for my bad English but I need your help so bad.... ;(
My level is quite low so when you explain I need some example codes to see and understand.

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Step 3 and 4 doesn't make sense. All integer numbers in a computer are stored in binary format. You can't convert to hexadecimal or decimal. What you can do is to print the value as hex or dec but that's not a conversion

Comment: Extracting the 2 from 8 can easily be done by simple boolean operations like masking and shifting.  You are familiar with boolean operations like OR, AND, XOR yes?

Comment: @4386427: Re “All integer numbers in a computer are stored in binary format”: That is certainly not true. Some integers are stored as decimal numerals using ASCII digit characters. Some are stored in BCD. JavaScript stores all numbers, even integers, in a floating-point format.

Comment: Guys, I think I explained it unclearly... What I need is showing the converted value result, not actually convert the real value.

Comment: ASCII, FP and BCD are all representations/interpretations of of binary data.  There is binary data and binary instruction codes, that's it, really.

Comment: @MartinJames: Do not confuse bits or strings of bits with binary. By itself “01100111” is a string of bits with no meaning. Binary applies meaning; it says to interpret each bit with a value depending on its position. Often “binary“ is used indiscriminately to refer to things made of bits, even being so sloppy as to refer to an executable as a “binary” when modern executables actually contain structured data, not raw binary to be loaded into memory. But, in the context of how integers are represented, “binary” means the positional number notation, in contrast to other formats.

Comment: @EricPostpischil a quickie net search is...not definitive.  Obviously, I don't deny that a binary number system exists, that is position-weighted and almost universally used to represent unsigned integers.  OTOH, a search for 'binary' gives results like 'This numbering system is the basis for all binary code, which is used to write digital data such as the computer processor instructions used every day'.  So...meh..:)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing a byte is the eight-bit byte *vulgaris*, an eight-byte integer is 64 bits. Then:

1. Include `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdint.h>`.
2. Define a 64-bit unsigned integer variable `x` using `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`.
3. Use `scanf("%" SCNu64, &x)` to read the number from input.
4. Test the return value of `scanf`. If it is not 1, for one number read, print an error message and exit the program.
5. The four parts of the number are the 16 bits at each of the bit positions 0, 16, 32, and 48. Right-shift `x` by 0, 16, 32, and 48 to move each part to the low bits.
6. After each shift, extract the low 16 bits. You can do this with an AND operation with a 16-bit mask, `0xffffu`, or you can do it by assigning the value to a `uint16_t` variable, which stores only 16 bits.
7. Print the numbers. If you have them in a `uint16_t` variable, you can print them with `printf("%" PRIu16, variable);`. If they are in some other variable or type of expression, you need a different conversion specifier, such as `PRIu64` if you have a `uint64_t` expression.